# Is this definition of a continuous random variable correct?

Tags: probability

I was a bit puzzled, because it seems like a discrete random variable would also satisfy the following definition:

> **Definition:** A random variable $X$ is **continuous** if there is a function $f(x)$ such that for any $c\le d$ we have $$\mathbb{P}(c \le X \le d) = \int_c^d f(x) \mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$

Source: [MIT OCW reading](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading5b.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a reasonable definition.  The problem you seem to be having, however, is why it works for continuous and not for discrete.  We can look at this for two cases:

1. If the random variable is discrete and $c = d$, then $P(c \leq X \leq d)$ for $c = d$ would just be $P(X=c)$, which could be some non-zero value.  The integral, however, would be $\int_{c}^{d}{f(x)dx}=\int_{c}^{c}{f(x)dx}=0$ every time. (In other words, by this definition, $P(X=c) = 0$ for all $c$, which is true for continuous functions but not for discrete functions.)
2. If the random variable is discrete and $c \neq d$, then $f(x)$ (being also discrete) will not be continuous (ie, it will be defined on the domain at the discrete values and not defined between them).  Since $f(x)$ is discontinuous at uncountably many points, it cannot be integrated as $\int_{c}^{d}{f(x)dx}$ when $c \neq d$.